# How to close Mongoose connection when App closes from debugger in VSCode

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm testing a Node.js project in VSCode but I'm concerned that my Mongoose connection is not closed when I restart using the Debugger.

[image]

I use the code below but when I close with the debugger `SIGINT signal received` doesn't print in the terminal.  `SIGINT` is triggered when `Ctrl C` is pressed so it must be different.  Does the Debugger send out any signal or perhaps is there another way to detect that the app has been stopped?

```
process.on('SIGINT', () => {
    console.log('SIGINT signal received.');
    mongoose.connection.close(() => {
        process.exit(0);
    });
});
```